# Creating choices field based on another modelForms entries

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I currently have 2 models, 1 for customers and 1 for JobCards

I would like to automatically add the "customers" data into the "JobCards" entries with a choices field.

However, I am getting the following error with my code: `TypeError: 'newCustomersClass' object is not subscribable`

Please see the following code

```
class newCustomersClass(models.Model):
customerName = models.CharField("Customer Name",max_length=50 , blank=True)
addressStreetNo = models.CharField(max_length=50 , blank=True)
addressStreet = models.CharField(max_length=50 , blank=True)
addressSuburb = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True )
addressCity = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True )

contact = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True )
mail = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True )
CellNo = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True )

customerClass = newCustomersClass.objects.all()
customers = []
for row in customerClass:
    rdict = {}
    rdict.customerName = row[0]
    customers.append(rdict)


class jobCardsClass(models.Model):
    customerName = models.CharField(choices=customers ,max_length=100 , blank=False , default=1)
```

Is it possible to append an array like this from a model form? Otherwise, what would be a better way to do so?

Comment: Had you tried to resolve it by creating **Form**?

Comment: @Mahmoud , yes I have , it returns `ImportError: cannot import name 'newCustomersClass' from partially initialized module 'main.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\KylePOG\Documents\GMA Programming\zipherJobCards\main\models.py)`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Foreign keys?

```
class jobCardsClass(models.Model):
    customerName = models.ForeignKey(to=newCustomersClass)
```